# ¿Cómo obtener el item seleccionado de un JComboBox y a su vez que liste todo a partir de ese Item?

Tags: java, c#

Lo que necesito saber es como hago que en un JComboBox me muestre el item seleccionado y a su vez me liste todo lo cargado en ese combo a partir de ese item seleccionado almacenado previamente, por ej:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ese combo pertenece a un ComboBox el cual está escrito en C#, yo quiero hacer lo mismo pero en java, ¿se entiende? Hasta el momento he logrado hacer esto solamente, mostrar solamente el item que se encuentra seleccionado previamente almacenado, pero no me lo lista los demás datos almacenados en mi BD los cuales hacen que mi JComboBox se llene.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solamente los datos se muestran si borro ese item y a medida que voy borrando va listando los item que cumplen con el autoComplete del mismo.

El combo se carga:

```
private DefaultComboBoxModel comboLocalidad() {
        DefaultComboBoxModel valor = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
        try {
            Connection miComando = AdministradorConfiguracion.obtenerComandoMySql();
            CallableStatement obtenerLocalidades = miComando.prepareCall("call obtener_localidades()");
            ResultSet rs = obtenerLocalidades.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                cboLocalidad.setModel(valor);
                valor.addElement(new Localidad(rs.getInt("Nro"), rs.getString("Localidad")));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al intentar auto completar busqueda:\n"
                    + e, "Error en la operación", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        return valor;
    }
```

Para cargar los datos del formulario hago:

```
private void cargarDatos() {
        obtener(idModificado);
        cliente.setNombre(txtNombre.getText());
        cliente.setApellido(txtApellido.getText());
        cliente.setDomicilio(txtDomicilio.getText());
        cliente.setTelefono(txtTelefono.getText());
        cliente.setFacebook(txtFacebook.getText());
        Localidad cbo = (Localidad) cboLocalidad.getSelectedItem();
        int id = cbo.getIdlocalidad();
        cliente.setIdlocalidad(id);
    }
```

El método **obtener()**

```
public void obtener(int idCli) {
    try {
        DefaultComboBoxModel valor = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
        Connection miComando = AdministradorConfiguracion.obtenerComandoMySql();
        CallableStatement obtenerCliente = miComando.prepareCall("call obtener_cliente(?)");
        obtenerCliente.setInt(1, idCli);
        obtenerCliente.execute();
        ResultSet rs = obtenerCliente.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            jtxtId.setText(String.valueOf(rs.getInt("idcliente")));
            txtNombre.setText(rs.getString("nombre"));
            txtApellido.setText(rs.getString("apellido"));
            txtDomicilio.setText(rs.getString("domicilio"));
            txtTelefono.setText(rs.getString("telefono"));
            txtFacebook.setText(rs.getString("facebook"));
            valor.addElement(new Localidad(rs.getInt("idlocalidad"), rs.getString("localidad")));
            cboLocalidad.setModel(valor);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al intentar obtener el cliente:\n"
                + e, "Error en la operación", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

El autoComplete:

```
private void autoCompletarLocalidad(String cadBus) {
        DefaultComboBoxModel valor = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
        try {
            Connection miComando = AdministradorConfiguracion.obtenerComandoMySql();
            CallableStatement obtenerLocalidades = miComando.prepareCall("call obtener_localidades_por_cadena(?)");
            obtenerLocalidades.setString(1, cadBus);
            ResultSet rs = obtenerLocalidades.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                valor.addElement(new Localidad(rs.getInt("Nro"), rs.getString("Localidad")));
            }
            if (valor.getSize() > 0) {
                cboLocalidad.setModel(valor);
                cboLocalidad.setSelectedItem(cadBus);
                cboLocalidad.showPopup();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al intentar auto completar busqueda:\n"
                    + e, "Error en la operación", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
```

El metodo que hace el **keyReleased:**

```
private void cboAutoComplete() {
        final JTextField textoBuscado = (JTextField) cboLocalidad.getEditor().getEditorComponent();
        textoBuscado.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        autoCompletarLocalidad(textoBuscado.getText());
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

¿Alguna idea de cómo puedo realizar lo que deseo hacer? He buscado, investigado pero no he dado con la solución. Desde ya, gracias.

Comment: Como se me ocurre que realices esto es de la siguiente manera : 1)Luego de la consulta a la base de datos recorras el `ResultSet` pero en vez de llenar directamente el `JComboBox` llenes una Lista (`java.util.List`) 2)Teniendo la lista cargada llenamos el `JComboBox` con los datos de la lista 3)Al seleccionar el valor del `JComboBox` buscamos su posicion en la lista y desplegamos desde su índice hasta el fin de la lista

Comment: Hola. Realice lo que sugerís de la siguiente manera: `List filterArray = new ArrayList()` luego lleno el Array con: `filterArray.add(new Localidad(rs.getInt("Nro"), rs.getString("Localidad")));` dentro del bugle `while` despues se lo grego al **JComboBox** de la siguiente manera: `if (filterArray.size() > 0) {
            cboLocalidad.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(filterArray.toArray()));
        }` eso en el metodo que carga solamente el combo, luego para obtener el item hice lo mismo pero en el metodo **obtener** pero no me a resultado, me sigue haciendo lo mismo de antes.